# Restful DDS execution

Tags: rest, data-distribution-service

I download restful-dds-1.0-src.tgz file from http://code.google.com/p/restful-dds/downloads/list website. I am using linux environment. From the ReadMe.txt file i execute the chatter application (CHATROOM TEST) up to scripts/startRESTfulDDS.sh and also view the html file from `http://ipaddress:8182/static/ajaxTest.html`. After that "run the Chatter application in the Tutorial directory by running scripts/Chatter.{sh,bat}." In here my problem arise. I am not able to see scripts folder and chatter.sh file inside the Tutorial folder. Please, help me what i did wrong.

I am using  opensplice DDS v5.5

```
GWT2.4.0, 
JDK 1.6, 
Restlet v2.0.14, 
Gson v2.2.2
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am not able to see scripts folder and
>   chatter.sh file inside the Tutorial folder

The `Tutorial` folder that is created is an exact copy of the OpenSpliceDDS tutorial, found in `$OSPL_HOME/examples/dcps/standalone/Java/Tutorial`. There seems to be a mismatch between the description in the `resful-dds README` and this tutorial because indeed, there is no `chatter.sh`. However, there is a `README.txt` inside the `Tutorial` directory which explains how to run `Chatter`:

```
Chatter [userid] [username]
  userid:   an integer number that uniquely identifies the sender of a message
            (Transmit a message with userid = -1 to terminate the MessageBoard.)
  username: the user-name other chatters will see when they receive one of your
            chat messages.

The executables classes are located in the chatroom package, but should be
started from the current directory in the following way:
...
java -classpath $OSPL_HOME/jar/dcpssaj.jar:bld chatroom.Chatter 1 Bill
```

Following this procedure, you should be able to run `Chatter`. Of course, you should first run `ospl start` to initialize the infrastructure.

By the way, it is not required that you run the java version of the tutorial -- any supported language should do. The OpenSpliceDDS installation itself should give you more information about running `Chatter` for different languages. The restful DDS webservice will pick up any data found on the DDS bus and expose it via HTTP, no matter what language the originating process was written in.

Comment: When i try to run the build file inside the restful-dds-1.1 it shows some run time errors like "java.lang.incompatibleclasschangeerror: found interface com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.jclasstype, but class was expected" error arise.

Comment: OK, I know nothing about that. I removed the remark from the answer.